GraphicsColumn misalignment
I am trying to plot a bunch of data in a columnar fashion but I have noticed a small misalignment appears when the y axis ranges are different and one increases the ImageSize. The x axis range is exactly the same for all plots.
Here is an example with some test functions (not my actual data):
GraphicsColumn[
{
Plot[x+1,{x,0.,5},PlotTheme->"FrameGrid",PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},Frame->{{True,True},{False,True}}],
Plot[x^2+1,{x,0.,5},PlotTheme->"FrameGrid",PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},Frame->{{True,True},{False,True}}],
Plot[x^3+1,{x,0.,5},PlotTheme->"FrameGrid",PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},Frame->{{True,True},{False,True}}],
Plot[x^4+1,{x,0.,5},PlotTheme->"FrameGrid",PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Red,Blue}]
},Spacings->0.,ImageSize->900
]

On my laptop I get the following result:


Please take a look at the PlotGrid function.

I saw that but how do I access it in mathematica? I am running 14.1 and there is no function called PlotGrid

I got it! I'll check it out!

Try specifying the image size for each plot as well as the whole plot:
is = 900;
GraphicsColumn[{Plot[x + 1, {x, 0., 5}, PlotTheme -> "FrameGrid", 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
   Frame -> {{True, True}, {False, True}}, ImageSize -> is], 
  Plot[x^2 + 1, {x, 0., 5}, PlotTheme -> "FrameGrid", 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
   Frame -> {{True, True}, {False, True}}, ImageSize -> is], 
  Plot[x^3 + 1, {x, 0., 5}, PlotTheme -> "FrameGrid", 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
   Frame -> {{True, True}, {False, True}}, ImageSize -> is], 
  Plot[x^4 + 1, {x, 0., 5}, PlotTheme -> "FrameGrid", 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, ImageSize -> is]}, 
 Spacings -> 0., ImageSize -> is]



that worked! wow I didn't think of it. Truth is I don't really understand how this ImageSize is supposed to work
